# What to do with the output of lex?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, lex

I have absolutely no background in compilers and started off on a "teach myself" journey. I am learning about lex using [this](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/lexyacc.pdf) tutorial and typed something like this into a file called `first.l`

```
%%
    /* match everything except newline */
.   ECHO;
    /* match newline */
\n ECHO;

%%

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I understand that lex is supposed to generate a tokenizer that will just echo everything it gets using the above `first.l` file. I went ahead and ran

`lex first.l`

It created a file called `lex.yy.c`. The tutorial then gives a few more examples and jumps to `yacc`. Can someone tell me what can be done with `lex.yy.c` file that is generated by lex? My thought was that I now have a tokenizer but how do I compile this file to a binary now? Using gcc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using GCC. You probably want to do something like this:

```
gcc -c file1.c
gcc -c file2.c
gcc -o result file1.o file2.o
```

The `-c` flag to GCC tells it not to link, but stop after generating an object file. Once you've compiled all the files, you can link it together by passing them all to `gcc`.

So in your case, you would just go ahead and compile the output file generated by `lex` to get the binary:

```
gcc -o output lex.yy.c
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to compile using gcc but wanted to know what to do with the file that lex generated. Turns out that I just had to compile it with gcc and it works as expected. Thanks for your time. I have edited your answer to add the final step. Hope you won't mind.